# MySQL JOIN statement cross join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm not good with the old JOIN statements and looking for a little friendly help. I have two tables, lets say table `Employee`:

```
   LastName DepartmentID
Rafferty    31
Jones   33
Steinberg   33
Robinson    34
Smith   34
John    NULL
```

and table `Department`:

```
DepartmentID    DepartmentName
31  Sales
33  Engineering
34  Clerical
35  Marketing
```

if I want to return results where `DepartmentID=31` AND only results where `Employee.DepartmentID = Department.DepartmentID`, so that the returned result would look like this:

```
Employee.LastName   Employee.DepartmentID   Department.DepartmentName
Rafferty    31  Sales
```

(we can  drop one of the DepartmentID's since they are the same) - what is the SQL statement that will accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.LastName, e.DepartmentID, d.DepartmentName
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Department d ON d.DepartmentID = e.DepartmentID
WHERE d.DepartmentID = 31
```

Comment: thanks, does the 'Department d' and 'Employee e' make 'd' and 'e' reusable variables?

Comment: @themerlinproject - no, it just creates aliases for the table names for use within that same query.  In this case I'm using it so I can simply type 'e' instead of 'Employee' for example.  Aliases are especially handy though when you join a table to itself.

Answer (score 0):

There's the metaphorical fish:

SELECT * FROM employee INNER JOIN department on employee.departmentId = department.departmentId WHERE departmentId = 31

And here's the metaphorical fishing lesson:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp (just press 'next')

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.LastName, e.DeparmentID, d.DepartmentName
FROM employee AS e INNER JOIN department AS d ON e.DepartmentID = e.DepartmentID
WHERE e.DepartmentID = 31
```

We'll use an `INNER JOIN` to match the records in each table using the `ON` section -> equating departmentid values between both tables.